# Confirm ODE given IVP

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given the following ode to solve:

$$\frac{dx}{dt}=-r(x(t)-x_e)+d_0e^{-\frac{t}{T}}$$

For which I compute:

$$x(t) = x_e+\frac{d_0}{r-\frac{1}{T}}e^{-\frac{t}{T}}+c_3e^{-rt}$$

And the IVP is $x(t_0)=x_e$ for which I get:

$$x(t) = x_e+\frac{d_0}{r-\frac{1}{T}} \Big[ e^{-\frac{t}{T}}-e^{r(t_0-t)-\frac{t_0}{T}} \Big]$$

Can someone please confirm my answers?

Comment: If you take your result, find $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$, substitute it into your first expression, does the equality hold? In other words, you can always test your solution, a very nice feature of DEQs.

Comment: Okay, managed to check my solution! Thanks Moo :)